# SQL Filter Out Customers If Two Records Match Criteria

Tags: sql

Ok, I want to only show customers where they don't have multiple records with different billing codes.  Billing codes are static.

```
OrderId   CustomerID    Billing Code
-------------------------------------
   1            1           1
   2            1           2
   3            2           1
   4            3           2
```

So in this case, I would want to show `OrderId`'s 3 and 4 and not 1 and 2, because `CustomerId` of 1 has entries for billing codes 1 and 2.

Thank you.

Comment: Ended up going with this, let me know if anyone has a better way. SELECT  *
FROM    TableNameHere AS TNH
WHERE   ( SELECT    COUNT(CustomerId)
          FROM      TableNameHere
          WHERE     CustomerId = TNH.CustomerId
                    AND ( BillingCode = 1
                          OR BillingCode = 2
                        )
          GROUP BY  CustomerId
        ) < 2

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of the obnoxious `&nbsp;` or `<br>` tags, either!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sub query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
where CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                         FROM tableName
                         GROUP BY CustomerID
                         HAVING count(CustomerID) >1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE T1 
WHERE 2 > (SELECT COUNT(CUSTOMERID) 
           FROM TABLE WHERE CUSTOMERID = T1.CUSTOMERID
           GROUP BY CUSTOMERID)
```

P.S: I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!